# Wildcard constraint that does not match a string

Tags: snakemake

I have the following rule where I'm trying to constraint the wildcard `sensor` to any string except those starting with `fitbit`. The problem I'm facing is that the regex I'm using seems to match any string, so is as if the rule does not exist (no output file is going to be generated).

```py
rule readable_datetime:
    input:
        sensor_input = rules.download_dataset.output
    params:
        timezones = None,
        fixed_timezone = config["READABLE_DATETIME"]["FIXED_TIMEZONE"]
    wildcard_constraints:
        sensor = "^(?!fitbit).*"  # ignoring fitbit sensors
    output:
        "data/raw/{pid}/{sensor}_with_datetime.csv"
    script:
        "../src/data/readable_datetime.R"
```

I'm getting this error message with a rule (`light_metrics`) that needs the output of `readable_time` with `sensor=light` as input

```py
MissingInputException in line 112 of features.snakefile:
Missing input files for rule light_metrics:
data/raw/p01/light_with_datetime.csv
```

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to stay away from regexes if I can and maybe this works for you.

Assuming sensor is a list like:

```
sensor = ['fitbit', 'spam', 'eggs']
```

In rule `readable_datetime` use

```
wildcard_constraints:
    sensor = '|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in sensor if x != 'fitbit'])
```

Explained: `re.escape(x)` escapes metacharacters in x so that we are not going to have spurious matches if x contains '.' or '*'. `x in sensor if x != 'fitbit'` should be self-explanatory and you can make it as complicated as you want. Finally, `'|'.join()` stitches everything together in a regex that can match only the items in sensor captured by the list comprehension.

(Why your regex doesn't work I haven't investigated...)

Answer (score 2):

My solution is simply to **remove the `^`** from the wildcards_constraint regex. This works because the regex is **applied to the whole path** containing the wildcard rather than just to the wildcard itself.

This is discussed briefly here:

https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/issues/904/problems-with-wildcard-constraints

My understanding is that the regex you specify for each wildcard is substituted in to a larger regex for the entire output path.

#### Without wildcard_constraints:

Searches for something like `data/raw/(.*)/(.*)_with_datetime.csv`, taking the first and second capture groups to be `pid` and `sensor` respectively.

#### With wildcard_constraints:

Searches for `data/raw/(.*)/((?!fitbit).*)_with_datetime.csv`, again taking the first and second capture groups to be `pid` and `sensor` respectively.

---

Here is a smaller working example:

```
rule all:                                                                                                                                                                            
    input:                                                                                                                                                                           
        "data/raw/p01/light_with_datetime.csv",                                                                                                                                      
        "data/raw/p01/fitbit_light_with_datetime.csv",                                                                                                                               
        "data/raw/p01/light_fitbit_with_datetime.csv",                                                                                                                               
        "data/raw/p01/light_fitbit_foo_with_datetime.csv",                                                                                                                           

rule A:                                                                                                                                                                              
    output:                                                                                                                                                                          
        "data/raw/{pid}/{sensor}_with_datetime.csv"                                                                                                                                  
    wildcard_constraints:                                                                                                                                                            
        sensor="(?!fitbit).*"                                                                                                                                                        
    shell:                                                                                                                                                                           
        "touch {output}"
```

When you run snakemake, it only complains about the file with sensor starting with `fitbit` being missing, but happily finds the others.

```
snakemake
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in line 1 of Snakefile:
Missing input files for rule all:
data/raw/p01/fitbit_light_with_datetime.csv
```